# Adding spaces before a value?

Tags: sql, formatting

I need to add spaces before a column in SQL.

For example, I have a column with a value `"00:99:88:aa"`. I need to add 3 spaces before the value to have the value `"   00:99:88:aa"`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to apply string concatenation.

#### For MySQL and MariaDB

```
SELECT concat('   ', '00:99:88:aa') FROM ...
```

or in the event of an update

```
UPDATE ...
SET value = concat('   ', value)
```

#### For SQL Server

```
SELECT '   ' + '00:99:88:aa' FROM ...
```

or in the event of an update

```
UPDATE ...
SET value = '   ' + value
```

#### For MS Access

```
SELECT '   ' & '00:99:88:aa' FROM ...
```

or in the event of an update

```
UPDATE ...
SET value = '   ' & value
```

#### For all the others

```
SELECT '   ' || '00:99:88:aa' FROM ...
```

or in the event of an update

```
UPDATE ...
SET value = '   ' || value
```

Comment: I need to update that column with white spaces before column value.not select the data. Need to update 6 lakhs rows of data.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

create a new column

```
alter table <table_name>

add <temp_column> varchar(10)
```

Update this new column with three space string

```
update <table_name> set <temp_column> = "   "
```

concatenate the two columns

```
select concat(temp_column,column1) from <table_name>
```

OR add a new column with this value

Answer (score 0):

ON MySql TRY:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = CONCAT("   ", `column`);
```

Comment: Hope already there is a answer present with similar code

Comment: I need to add for 6 lakhs rows of data I need to update the column with 3 spaces before a value in sql sever